# How to Save whole Jtable into database instead saving in txt file

Tags: java, sql, jtable, load, tablemodel

the following two codes save /load the whole Jtable to/from txt file.

what i need to do is to save whole contents in Database (on One cell only)  then read the whole Jtable contents back to Jtable.
Please how to do that?

```
  private void saveTable(File file) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(file));
            out.writeObject(tableModel.getDataVector());
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}





    private void loadTable(File file) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(file));
        Vector rowData = (Vector)in.readObject();
        Iterator itr = rowData.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            tableModel.addRow((Vector) itr.next());
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a table in the database containing all the fields that are in the `JTable`, and each `JTable` row will be retrieved from the database as a single row because saving the whole `JTable` data in a single field in the database does not make sense at all.

Comment: Thanks Jad:But in my case i want to save it as Template :means there are default template , then modify it then save it again with new added data, but could we do it in that way save the whole Jtable in one cell as we did in file or not?